# Modal doesn't open on all buttons

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

As my title already says, I have an issue with a modal not opening on all buttons.

Here is the situation:

I have a page that displays all applications a user has sent for different jobs. So it may be just one, or up to whatever.
It looks like this:

[image]

Now if the user wants to cancel the application he can press the button "Bewerbung zurückziehen", then the modal opens to give a heads up that all data will be lost and if he is sure, in the modal he can confirm it or go back. Everything works fine for the first post on the site, but for all other posts just nothing happens, so the modal doesn't open.

Here is my code:

1. The blade file that displays all posts:

```js
@foreach($bewerbungen as $bewerbung)
                    @foreach($stellenanzeigen_names as $stellenanzeigen_name)
                        @if($bewerbung->Stellenanzeigen_ID === $stellenanzeigen_name->Stellenanzeigen_ID)
                            <div
                                class="p-10 grid-cols-3 grid-rows-3 gap-4 shadow-2xl mb-10 bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 border-solid border-2 border-black rounded-lg">
                                <!--Card 1-->
                                    <div
                                        class="overflow-hidden row-span-3 bg-gray-100 shadow-2xl border-solid border-2 border-gray-500 rounded-lg">
                                        <div class="pt-4 pl-4">
                                            {{ $stellenanzeigen_name->Titel }}
                                            <hr class="border-black">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="pt-4 pl-8 font-medium text-xl font-bold font-serif">
                                            ID der Bewerbung: {{ $bewerbung->Bewerbung_ID }}</div>
                                        <div class="pt-4 pl-8 pb-3 font-medium text-xl font-bold font-serif">
                                            ID der Stellenanzeige: {{ $bewerbung->Stellenanzeigen_ID }}</div>

                                        <div class="w-1/4 mb-4 pl-4">
                                            <div class="font-medium text-base font-bold font-serif mb-4 pb-3">
                                                <button type="submit" id="delete_appl_btn" name="delete_appl_btn"
                                                        class="mb-4 pb-3 w-full text-white px-4 py-3 rounded text-base font-medium
                                                                bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 float-right shadow transition
                                                                duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100
                                                                shadow-2xl border-2 w-full p-4 rounded-lg">
                                                    Bewerbung zurückziehen
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
```

Here is the code for the modal:

```
<div id="delete_application_modal" class="modal fixed ml-96 top-20 mx-auto p-5 border w-96 shadow-lg rounded-md bg-white hidden">
                        <div class="mt-3 text-center text-xl">
                            Bewerbung zurückziehen
                            <div class="text-center text-sm mt-4">
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="items-center px-4 py-3">
                            <label for="delete_application" class="sr-only">Bewerbung zurückziehen</label>

                            <form action="{{ route('delete', $bewerbung->Bewerbung_ID) }}" method="post">
                                @csrf
                                <button type="submit" id="ok_btn" class="mb-4 pb-3 w-full text-white px-4 py-3 rounded text-base font-medium
                                                bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 float-right shadow transition
                                                duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100
                                                shadow-2xl border-2 w-full p-4 rounded-lg">
                                    Bewerbung zurückziehen
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div class="items-center px-4 py-3">
                            <button id="back_btn_tel" class="mb-4 pb-3 w-full text-white px-4 py-3 rounded text-base font-medium
                                                bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 float-right shadow transition
                                                duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100
                                                shadow-2xl border-2 w-full p-4 rounded-lg">
                                zurück
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @if(session()->has('message'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session()->get('message') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <script>
                        var delete_appl_modal = document.getElementById("delete_application_modal");

                        var open_modal = document.getElementById("delete_appl_btn");

                        var back_btn = document.getElementById("back_btn_tel");

                        open_modal.onclick = function () {
                            delete_appl_modal.style.display = "block";
                        }

                        back_btn.onclick = function () {
                            delete_appl_modal.style.display = "none";
                        }

                        window.onclick = function (event) {
                            if (event.target == modal) {
                                delete_appl_modal.style.display = "none";
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
```

Honestly, I have zero clue why it works for the first but not for the others, they have the same buttons, with the same name, id & everything.
Maybe one of you had a similar issue. I wish you all happy holidays!

Edit:
New code to open the modal:

```
    <script>
var delete_appl_modal = document.querySelector('#cancel_appl_modal');
    
    
var open = document.querySelector('#open_btn');
    
var back_btn = document.querySelector('#back_btn_tel');
    
open.onclick = function () {
                                                delete_appl_modal.style.display = "block";
                                            }
    
back_btn.onclick = function () {
                                                delete_appl_modal.style.display = "none";
                                            }

window.onclick = function (event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
                                                    delete_appl_modal.style.display = "none";
                                                }
                                            }
                                        </script>
```

When I use `querySelectorALl` then the first one doesn't work anymore as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) property is expected to be unique within a page, so when using [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) once an element with that `id` has been located it doesn't continue searching for others.

As you have multiple `button` elements that you want to target, you will need to us something like [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) or [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to target every element that should trigger the modal to open.

An example to get you on the right direction.

```html
<button class="open-modal">Button A</button>
<button class="open-modal">Button B</button>
<button class="open-modal">Button C</button>
```

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.open-modal');

buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    // this is where you would open the modal
    // delete_appl_modal.style.display = 'block';
    console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
  })
});
```

[Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0ts3w9e/)

Comment: hey @peppermintology :) I had family over for Christmas so I wasn't able to answer. I changed the code now but the issue is the same :/ I will edit my question, maybe you can help me. I am very new to JS :D

Comment: @newbie I have added an example for you.

Comment: ahhh i was so hard on the wrong path lol :D the example was perfect, thanks a lot!